# What to store in a session for a Rest client

Tags: rest, session, openid

I am busy designing REST-based service and battling with understanding how security works on the web.  This is a green fields solution so I can design it to support all the new standards and services in the best way possible.  Including following all the OpenID best practices (I believe the time is right to let all users sign up only with OpenID)

I will eventually publish the API, but I will first create a reference implementation of a web client and a mobile client for this system.

After the user has been authenticated the client provides the Auth code to the service (Is this true for all OpenID OPs?).  A session must then be recorded on the server.  Do I store the Auth Token obtained from the OpenID OP?  I don't want to connect to the OpenID OP over-and-over, but this could possibly be cached?  Do I store just the session ID and the user's fully qualified OpenID?  Do I also store a copy of the user's local user profile in the server sessions table (to eliminate a second query?)

When the client makes a second request, it needs to supply something ... generally it seems like people use a Session_ID, but I'm thinking that since there may be third-party web-sites between a browser-based client and the service, that middle layer could potentially abuse the session-ID?

It may be convenient for a web site to use the session-id to build some fancy views by making additional calls to the service "on behalf of the user", eg to build a view.  But how do I know that these subsequent requests were made on behalf of a legitimate connected user, and not just one who has had their session-ID recorded by this man in the middle?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenID so I'm not going to answer, but in principle you shouldn't store sessions on the server side. REST should be stateless. Yes, the right approach in REST is to cache the OpenID session.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I've read that keeping a user logged in breaks the "stateless" requirement for REST, but that people do it any way because the alternative is to authenticate every request.  This practice it seems is frowned upon but considered a necessary evil because authenticating every request is "expensive".  I don't havethe reference on hand but it may have been an older document.... so what is the recommendation?

Comment: The recommendation is to follow whatever solves your problems, as long as you understand the REST constraints. By storing some state on the server you'll lose some visibility and scalability. An alternative is to have an authentication scheme local to your server. That's what API tokens are for. Once authenticated over OpenID you provide a token that your server can validate on-the- fly, without having to check storage or another service somewhere. This is not expensive at all.